# AWS Lambda [ERROR] Function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am creating my (very first) Lambda function. The Lambda is designed to turn ON/OFF a Philips HUE bulb. The trigger for the Lambda function is an AWS IoT (Dash) Button.

However after triggering my Lambda function I am receiving the following error message:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: lambda_handler() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 131, in handle_event_request
    response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)
```

Can anyone offer any insight into what is wrong with my Python code? Thanks!

```
import requests,json

bridgeIP = "PublicIPAddress:999"
userID = "someone"
lightID = "2"

def lambda_handler(lightID):
 url = "http://"+bridgeIP+"/api/"+userID+"/lights/"+lightID
 r = requests.get(url)
 data = json.loads(r.text)
 if data["state"]["on"] == False:
     r = requests.put(url+"/state",json.dumps({'on':True}))
 elif data["state"]["on"] == True:
     r = requests.put(url+"/state",json.dumps({'on':False}))

lambda_handler(lightID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler function should be defined as:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lightID = event
    ...
```

From [AWS Lambda Function Handler in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html):

> `event` – AWS Lambda uses this parameter to pass in event data to the handler. This parameter is usually of the Python dict type. It can also be list, str, int, float, or NoneType type.
>
> When you invoke your function, you determine the content and structure of the event. When an AWS service invokes your function, the event structure varies by service.
>
> `context` – AWS Lambda uses this parameter to provide runtime information to your handler.

It is quite likely that your `event` merely contains the Light ID as shown by your code, but it is best to call it `event` to recognize that it is a value being passed into the Lambda function, but your code is then choosing to interpret it as the `lightID`.

Also, your code **should not** be calling the `lambda_handler` function. The AWS Lambda service will do this when the function is invoked.

Finally, you might want to take advantage of Python 3.x f-strings, which make prettier-format strings:

```py
import requests
import json

bridgeIP = "PublicIPAddress:999"
userID = "someone"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lightID = event
    url = f"http://{bridgeIP}/api/{userID}/lights/{lightID}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({'on': not data["state"]["on"]}))
```

Comment: Thank you for this information on how to define the handler function.  I am now getting a new error message; related to the following line of code:  
`r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({'on': not data["state"]["on"]}))`  
  
The error message reads:  
`[ERROR] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`  
  
I noticed that the (final) code block (that you suggested) does not assign a value to "LightID".  (I assigned a value of "2" to "LightID", in line 5 of my original code.)

Comment: Sorry.  
I wish my response was formatted better than it currently is!  
I tried putting "double spaces" where I wanted line breaks, but to no avail. :/

Comment: It seems to be complaining about the content of `data` and the inability to apply `["state"]["on"]` to it. You'll need to debug further to figure out what's going on, since I don't have access to what the URL is returning -- I mostly copied your code sample.

Comment: Understood. However, at some point I need to set the my variable lightID equal to 2. Was I right to do that BEFORE defining the lambda_handler() function?

Comment: It's your code, do what you wish. My suggested code is setting `lightID` from the value passed into the `event`, since that's what your code sample seemed to be doing. If you are always using the same value for `lightID` rather than passing it into the Lambda function, then, yes, you should hard-code that value. You can do it either within the Lambda function, or outside of it as a global variable.

Comment: The final version of my fully-functional python script can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970085/aws-lambda-error-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-get

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that two positional arguments are given to your  `lambda_handler` function, but the function is defined to accept only one.

Lambda automatically gives two arguments to a handler function, so you need to define your function to accept two arguments.

You can do that by changing your function definition to be:

```
def lambda_handler(lightID, lambda_context):
```