# AWS Lambda ERROR: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that is designed to turn ON/OFF my Philip HUE lightbulbs. I am able to execute the python script & it runs (error-free) on my local machine. However, when I trigger the Lambda function (using an IoT Button) I get the following error message.

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler
    bulbStatus = nested_get(data,["state","on"])
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in nestedDictLookup
    internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
```

I think the error relates the the following line of code:

```
internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
```

However, I am almost certain that the "internal_dict_value" variable is a dictionary, NOT a list.  To verify, I inserted the following line of code into my script:

```
internal_dict_value = input_dict
print (internal_dict_value)
```

Here is the output that I received:

```
{
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 254,
        "hue": 8597,
        "sat": 121,
        "effect": "none",
        "xy": [
            0.4452,
            0.4068
        ],
        "ct": 343,
        "alert": "select",
        "colormode": "xy",
        "mode": "homeautomation",
        "reachable": false
    },
    "swupdate": {
        "state": "noupdates",
        "lastinstall": "2019-07-26T19:09:58"
    },
    "type": "Extended color light",
    "name": "Couch Light",
    "modelid": "LCT016",
    "manufacturername": "Philips",
    "productname": "Hue color lamp",
    "capabilities": {
        "certified": true,
        "control": {
            "mindimlevel": 1000,
            "maxlumen": 800,
            "colorgamuttype": "C",
            "colorgamut": [
                [
                    0.6915,
                    0.3083
                ],
                [
                    0.1700,
                    0.7000
                ],
                [
                    0.1532,
                    0.0475
                ]
            ],
            "ct": {
                "min": 153,
                "max": 500
            }
        },
        "streaming": {
            "renderer": true,
            "proxy": true
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "archetype": "sultanbulb",
        "function": "mixed",
        "direction": "omnidirectional",
        "startup": {
            "mode": "custom",
            "configured": true,
            "customsettings": {
                "bri": 254,
                "ct": 346
            }
        }
    },
    "uniqueid": "00:00:88:08:03:fd:4a:e2-0a",
    "swversion": "1.46.13_r26312",
    "swconfigid": "9DC82D22",
    "productid": "Philips-LCT316-1-A17ECLv5"
}
```

Here is the script that I am working with. If you have any inspirational ideas, please share them! Thanks.

```
import requests,json

bridgeIP = "IP_Address_Here"
userID = "userID_here"
lightID = "4" #Represents the ID assigned to lightbulb, in the living room.

def lambda_handler(lightID, lambda_context):
    url = f"http://{bridgeIP}/api/{userID}/lights/{lightID}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    def nested_get(input_dict, nested_key):
        internal_dict_value = input_dict
        for k in nested_key:
            internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
            if internal_dict_value is None:
                return None
        return internal_dict_value


    bulbStatus = nested_get(data,{"state","on"})
    #the nested_get() function captures the dict value, assigned to the "on" key.
    #{"state":{"on":{True}} or {"state":{"on":{False}}

    if bulbStatus == False:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":True}))
    elif bulbStatus == True:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":False}))

lambda_handler(lightID, 4)
```

The last line in my script calls the lambda_handler() function. I'm told that I do not need this line because my Lambda calls the function when the Lambda Function is triggered. However I (believe) that I do need to manually call the function, when executing the script on my local machine.

Comment: "However I (believe) that I do need to manually call the function, when executing the script on my local machine." that's true but you should comment out that line before uploading the lambda to AWS. Can you please point out specifically which line of code is line 21? Based on the code you provided line 21 is a blank line, so obviously what you pasted isn't exactly what is running Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [@JakePearse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716738/jakepearse) I was able to resolve the issue.

Here is the final version of my (fully-functional) python script.

```
import requests,json

bridgeIP = "IP/FQDN_Here:port_here"
userID = "userHash_here"
lightID = "2"

def lambda_handler(event, lambda_context):
    url = f"http://{bridgeIP}/api/{userID}/lights/{lightID}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    def nested_get(input_dict, nested_key):
        internal_dict_value = input_dict
        for k in nested_key:
            if type(internal_dict_value) is dict:
                internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
                if internal_dict_value is None:
                    return None
        return internal_dict_value

    bulbStatus = nested_get(data,["state","on"])

    if bulbStatus == False:
        requests.put(f"{url}/state",json.dumps({"on":True}))
    elif bulbStatus == True:
        requests.put(f"{url}/state",json.dumps({"on":False}))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Mission accomplished!')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with changing the value of internal_dict_value during the loop is you dont know what type it's going to hold.
try something like `if type(internal_dict_value) is dict:`

Comment: That worked! I can now trigger my Lambda function, on AWS. However the function fails to toggle the lightbulb. The CloudWatch log shows a START RequestId, END RequestId, and REPORT RequestId message. If I trigger the Lambda function again, the 2nd CloudWatch log reflects two sets of these messages (START, END, REPORT, START, END, REPORT). Why is this odd behavior occurring?

Comment: Nevermind. I looked at the time stamp and realized that the multiple entries correlated with the times that the Lambda function was triggered. However this still doesn't explain why the lambda_handler() function isn't toggling the lightbulb. Do I need to define the "lightID" variable at a different indentation level?